# AWS MSK Public cluster authentication with SASL/SCRAM

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, aws-msk, sasl-scram

The configuration of AWS MSK is public and a secret is attached to it.The security setting is set to SASL_SCRAM enabled, allow.everyone.if.no.acl.found=false and auto.create.topics.enable=true is set as written. I'm trying to connect to the cluster with the given code below.But receiving an error "code 29:TOPIC_AUTHORIZATION_FAILED"

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
from time import sleep
from json import dumps
import logging
import pulumi
import pulumi_kafka as kafka

   producer = KafkaProducer(sasl_mechanism="SCRAM-SHA-512",api_version=(0,11,5),
    sasl_plain_password="secret-password",request_timeout_ms= 500000,max_block_ms=60000,
    sasl_plain_username="secret-username",
    security_protocol="SASL_SSL",
    bootstrap_servers=['b-2xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxx:9198', 'b-3xxxxxxxxx.xxxxx:9198', 'b-1xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxx:9198'],
                         value_serializer=lambda x: 
                         dumps(x).encode('utf-8'))


test = kafka.Acl("test",
    acl_resource_name="numtest",
    acl_resource_type="Topic",
    acl_principal="User:secret-username",
    acl_host="*",
    acl_operation="All",
    acl_permission_type="Allow")
    

for e in range(500):
    data = {'number' : e}
    producer.send('numtest', value=data)
    sleep(5)
```